# Modifying Angular array object onload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Background: I'm using Bootstrap's `breadcrumb` to output `/ some / path / to / my / file`. To ensure the breadcrumb stays within the width of the page I want to compare the length of the breadcrumb text with the width of its container. If the width of text exceeds the container, I will modify the breadcrumb data array until it fits, i.e. `/ ... / to / file`

Because the breadcrumb data exists in an array and is not hard-coded in the page, it's not possible to measure the width of the text UNTIL the page has fully loaded.

I would use `<body onload="widthChecker()">` but this won't work with Angular, and I don't believe `ng-init` will work either.

Here is my code so far...

```js
var folderArray = [{
  folder: 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
}, {
  folder: 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy'
}, {
  folder: 'the quick brown fox jumps over the'
 }, {
  folder: 'the quick brown fox jumps over'
  }, {
  folder: 'the quick brown fox jumps'
}];    
    
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('AppController', function() {
    this.files = folderArray;
  });

})();

function checkWidths() {

  var cWidth = document.getElementById("breadcrumb-container").offsetWidth;
  var tWidth = document.getElementById("breadcrumb-container").scrollWidth;
  
/*
  while (tWidth > cWidth) {
    
     Condense objects in folderArray into ellipsis until the breadcrumb fits
  
  }
*/
}
```

```css
#breadcrumb-container {
  width: 100%;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.breadcrumb {
  display: table;
}
     
.breadcrumb li {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
    
<body ng-controller="AppController as box" onload="checkWidths();">
  
<div id="breadcrumb-container">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li ng-repeat="file in box.files"><a href="#">{{ file.folder }}</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>  
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

> I would use  but this won't work with
>   Angular, and I don't believe ng-init will work either.

This is not true. You can use the following piece of code, for example, to get access to the scope and call an Angular function

```
var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('someId'));
scope.condense_objects();
```

...where condense_objects is the function that checks width and updates the array till it fits

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Would you be able to help me as I'm a bit unsure what to do with the code.